# Displaying an image from database in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to display an image from my database in my view, but i cannot make it work.

I am getting this result on f5 :

[image]

Here is how my model looks :

```
    public int CompId { get; set; }
    public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public HttpPostedFileBase UploadImage { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string ImageBase64 => System.Convert.ToBase64String(ImageData);
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
```

and the view :

```
   @model ekspo.Models.Company

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
    <h4>Company</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ImageData)

        </dt>

        <dd>
            @*@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ImageData)*@
            <img src="data:image/type;base64,@Model.ImageBase64)" />
        </dd>
```

Comment: Try removing that trailing ")" in your img src.

Comment: If that doesn't work, can we see your Controller code?

Comment: oh, thank you, mate. this is unbeliavable. i lost more then an hour. it was the  ")"

Comment: Check this example: http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Display-Image-from-Database-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line

```
<img src="data:image/type;base64,@Model.ImageBase64)" />
```

to

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,@Model.ImageBase64" />
```

(just removing that trailing ).

And if the desired image type isn't jpg, change that accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use asp image control to display image on page.
1.get the image url  from database.
2.bind the url to to image control 
Or try this
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-image-from-database-in-Image-control-without-using-Generic-Handler-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: i want to upload an image, not an url